# neo4j local cluster start failed

Tags: deployment, neo4j, cypher, cluster-computing, neo4jclient

I am trying to set up a **local cluster** in neo4j and following this tutorial (https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/local-causal-cluster/#tutorial-local-cluster-configure-cores). I have downloaded the latest **enterprise version 4.1.1** and have followed all the steps mentioned in the tutorial. However I am confused at one step where it is mentioned that we should move to bin directory and run command "`neo4j start`" . When I run this command it says neo4j service not found so I searched about it and found that I should install neo4j as a service first then the start command will start the service. When I install it the service will run for the core-01 instance, following the tutorial for core-02 and core-03 I am supposed to start neo4j also but again the start command will not work unless I install it.

Following this am I supposed to install 3 different services or it is supposed to be a single service for the whole cluster of 3 instances? If single then the neo4j service will always points to the **core-01** instance.

Skipping start command If I run the command `neo4j console` in the bin directory of 3 instances then I get this error in all three consoles

> [image: Database 'system' is waiting for a total of 3 core members...]

How I am supposed to handle this?? Am I not setting **neo4j** service properly or there is some issue in configuration ?